# next js image component error "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, next.js

i am fetching data from tmdb api .But the image doesn't load so i open the image in the new tab .then it shows

> "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid
> **so how to resolve the issue**

Comment: Follow this issue on vercel github: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/27973

Comment: For me this happened when I had a custom dockerfile to build the app and it wasn't including the next.config.js (and therefore my allowed hosts).

Answer (score 4):

Have you added the domain of the images to the next config ?

below is an example:

```
//next.config.js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webp: {
    preset: "default",
    quality: 100,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["randomuser.me", "firebasestorage.googleapis.com"],
  },
  //Internationalization
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "it"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
};
```

Comment: From the [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image-legacy#domains): "We recommend configuring strict `remotePatterns` instead of `domains` in order to protect your application from malicious users. Only use domains if you own all the content served from the domain."

Answer (score 2):

I had forgotten to add the X-Forwaded-For and X-Real-IP headers in nginx which caused an issue with image domains i had specified in next.config.js

If you are serving with http

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_pass  http://somehost:port;                                                                               
    }
```

If you are serving with uWSGI check you are including the params file as per
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site

Answer (score 1):

What it worked in my case, was to do a clean reload of browser.

In Chrome, it is `CTRL + SHIFT + R`

Answer (score 1):

If you have this error with Nextjs 13 with an Nginx reverse proxy setup.
You may need to adjust your nginx config like so.

Adding a location block for /_next/image which passes to localhost/_next/image

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3011/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;    
}
    location /_next/image {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3011/_next/image; 
}
```

Additionally if you have locally hosted (in public folder) but dynamic image urls, for example, pages which generated from json data received in the component,
Next/Image component failed to work when I treated my local url's as remote urls with any Nginx config.

This pattern did not work

```
    //No static import above component
    export const component = ({ section}) => {
        <Image
          src={`https://example.com/${section.src}`}
          alt={section.alt}
          priority='true'
          fill
          sizes="100vw"
          style={{
            objectFit: "cover",
            objectPosition: { backgroundposition }
          }} />
```

This pattern worked.

```
 //No static import above component
 export const component = ({ section}) => {
    <Image
      src={`${section.src}`} // Relative path '/images/image.jpg'
      alt={section.alt}
      priority='true'
      fill
      sizes="100vw"
      style={{
        objectFit: "cover",
        objectPosition: { backgroundposition }
      }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the nginx `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to `http` resolved the issue completely:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Appended line
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
  }
```

**Note**: my next.js app is being served by `pm2` on port `4000` and nginx is the reverse proxy

Answer (score -1):

i was facing the same issue although i am hosting my images on cloudinary and it does work if i use the normal `<img/>` tag
so i changed the nextjs version on `package.json` as bellow and it worked just fine:
hope it woud work for u as well

```
 "dependencies": {
   ...
  "next": "11.0.1",
   ...

 }
```

Comment: Fixing to the old next version is not a maintainable solution. At some point you will have to upgrade, no?