# How to load protected S3 images with Next.js Image component?

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I'm trying to make a photo gallery app that gets its photos from an S3 bucket. The images are fetched through presigned urls. The problem is that when I use the `Image` component from Next, I get the following error: `"url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid`. I can't seem to find the problem. I already configured the domain in the next.config.js file.

Comment: What version of Next.js are you using?

Comment: Yep, that was it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [next js image component error "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675288/next-js-image-component-error-url-parameter-is-valid-but-upstream-response-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: Upgrade Next.js